# How to copy an object from one type to another in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, design-patterns, type-conversion, converters

I have the following situation:
Class A and Class B have completely identical source code.
I have an array from A and have to convert it to array from B, in order to pass it as a parameter in method whom argument is from type B.

```
A[] foo = new A[] ;
//here getBar in certain situations accepts B[], but foo is always A[]
bar = BarFactory.getBar(foo);
```

I know it is a strange scenario but I am writing some kind of adapter for an existing infrastructure, which have really strange architecture I cannot see any way to sidestep this conversion. I cannot change the source of B and cannot have any hard reference to B. I also cannot make another methods to A because it have to be exact copy of B.

What would be the best way to make that conversion? Is there some kind of pattern for creating a Convertor class or something similar to this?

I know that the question may sound stupid but please don't "kill" me. I just want to do it in the best way.

Comment: Give a read to this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Thanks for the link Yuri. Using OAP is exactly what I'm trying to do but due to the architecture of the application I'm trying to adapt, it is not possible to use it straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might depend on how complex A and B are, but since you are positive that the code is the same, copying all the properties of an object A to a new object B should produce the expected result.

Apache has a project `commons-beanutils` that might help you in this task:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo[i], newFoo[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It looks to be promising but I will prefer not to use third party code here. No matter of that I will check it.

Comment: @Crypto Using third party code is actually a recommended course of action in modern programming, and straight-copying of their implementation might be a breach of licence. That said, it shouldn't be too hard to achieve, it is basically using reflection to get all the properties of one class (by getters I think) and setting them in the other.

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility to breach their license and I won't straight copy their implementation of course. I'm just searching for something like a guideline here on how to write something similar.

Comment: As long as you dont have complete access to every member of your objects you will have to rely on sth. that uses reflection either write it yourself or use well tested libraries of others (like the one Delharis mentioned)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this :

```
B[] b = (B[]) foo
```

Where foo is an array of class A

Comment: This would only work if both share the same interface. OP mentioned identical source code but no shared interface.

Comment: Yes. The problem here is that they cannot share the same interfaces.